# An issue with jQuery .html function

Tags: jquery

I'm working on delta calculator

Here's fragment my index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="delta.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<form>
<h2>Rozwiąż równanie kwadratowe: </h2>

<div id="values">
  <input type="number" id="a" value="0"> x<sup>2</sup> +
  <input type="number" id="b" value="0"> x +
  <input type="number" id="c" value="0"> = 0 </br>
  </div>
 <br>

<input type="submit" value="Count Delta" onclick="delta()">
    <br>

    <p>Delta: </p><div id="result"></div>

</form>




</body>
```

and part of my script:

```
function delta() {

    var a = $('#a').val();
    var b = $('#b').val();
    var c = $('#c').val();

    if(a === 0) {
        return null;
    }

    var bkwadrat = b * b;
    var minus = 4 * a * c;
    var delta = bkwadrat - minus;

    $('#result').html(delta);
```

When I click on "Count delta" the value shows up for a moment, then it disappear. I'm trying to fix this for a long time, maybe someone see what's wrong here. I've already tried using **.text** instead of **.html**.

Greetings

Comment: Your form is submitting and reloading the page. Prevent the default action of the button or return false.

Comment: Change it from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form. Or get rid of the `<form>` tag if you don't need to submit anything.

Comment: thank you @JasonP and **Barmar**